# Change Button background-color when input:hover

Tags: html, css, button, input, hover

I need change button background color on hover input. Changing the color of the button when hovering over the button is not a problem, and when hovering over the input it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```css
.menu__search {
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu__search input {
    transition: background 0.5s ease, color 0.3s linear !important;
}
.menu__search input:hover {
    background-color: yellow !important;
    color: black !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.menu__search input:hover::placeholder {
    font-weight: 500;
    color: green;
}
.menu__search input:hover button {
    background: red;
}
.menu__search button:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu__search">
    <input id="input_search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="search" class="menu-input">
    <button type="button" id="menu__search-button" class="menu-btn-search>
      <i class="fa fa-search">Search</i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use + selector [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) for select next element in DOM (without any js)

```css
.menu__search {
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu__search input {
    transition: background 0.5s ease, color 0.3s linear !important;
}
.menu__search input:hover {
    background-color: yellow !important;
    color: black !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.menu__search input:hover::placeholder {
    font-weight: 500;
    color: green;
}
.menu__search input:hover + button {
    background: red;
}
.menu__search button:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu__search">
    <input id="input_search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="search" class="menu-input">
    <button type="button" id="menu__search-button" class="menu-btn-search>
      <i class="fa fa-search">Search</i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ele = document.getElementById("input_search");
ele.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    var button = document.getElementById("menu__search-button");
    button.classList.add("bg");
})

ele.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    var button = document.getElementById("menu__search-button");
    button.classList.remove("bg");
})
```

```css
.menu__search {
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu__search input {
    transition: background 0.5s ease, color 0.3s linear !important;
}
.menu__search input:hover {
    background-color: yellow !important;
    color: black !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.menu__search input:hover::placeholder {
    font-weight: 500;
    color: green;
}
.menu__search input:hover button {
    background: red;
}
.menu__search button:hover {
    background: red;
}

.bg {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu__search">
    <input id="input_search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="search" class="menu-input">
    <button type="button" id="menu__search-button" class="menu-btn-search">
      <i class="fa fa-search">Search</i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added class bg and removed when mouse leave.
you can add any bg color. currently I have added pink

Comment: Any reason for dislike?